# case en consulta update mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, update, mysqldb

Buen día Comunidad, hoy me tope con esta dificultad de un procedimiento almacenado,
porfavor ayúdenme, ya me preocupe.

quiero actualizar las diferentes columnas con el valor de 'b', condicionando al valor de 'c'

```
...
... PROCEDURE `buscador_active`(IN a INT, IN b INT, IN c INT)
...
    UPDATE  
                masterDB.buscador A SET
                    CASE c
                        WHEN 1 THEN A.Fosrs_active = b
                        WHEN 2 THEN A.Guiee_active = b
                        WHEN 3 THEN A.Mersa_active = b
                        WHEN 4 THEN A.Camsn_active = b
                        WHEN 5 THEN A.Ersur_active = b
                        WHEN 6 THEN A.Sarme_active = b
                        WHEN 7 THEN A.Furic_active = b
                        ELSE NULL
                    END CASE;
                WHERE   
                    A.Id_user = a;
...
```

se me ocurría que existía algo mas interesante a tener que hacer algo como esta recurrente forma de conseguirlo,

```
...
      CASE c
                    WHEN 9 THEN
                        Update...
                    WHEN 8 THEN
                       Update...
                    WHEN 7 THEN
                       Update...
                    WHEN 6 THEN
                        Update...
                    WHEN 5 THEN
                       Update...
                    WHEN 4 THEN
                        Update...
                    WHEN 3 THEN
                        Update...
                    WHEN 2 THEN
                      Update...
                    ELSE    
                       Update..
                END CASE;   
...
```

digamos que quiero evitar hacer tanto código repetido.

Comment: No sé que quieres hacer; pero después de SET va un nombre de columna.

Comment: ho lo siento editare después, el objetivo es que según el valor de 'c', realice las actualizaciones en las diferentes columnas que hay usando el valor de 'b',
ya que mi otra alternativa es hacer multiples lineas repetidas de la consulta en este caso UPDATE, dentro de cada caso Case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` puede resultar verboso para casos simples, la alternativa es `if()`.

```
UPDATE master.buscador A
  SET A.Fosrs_active = if( c=1, b, null )
    , A.Guiee_active = if( c=2, b, null )
    , A.Mersa_active = if( c=3, b, null )
    , A.Camsn_active = if( c=4, b, null )
    , A.Ersur_active = if( c=5, b, null )
    , A.Sarme_active = if( c=6, b, null )
    , A.Furic_active = if( c=7, b, null )
  WHERE A.Id_user = a;
```

Comment: Excelente aporte, sutil me gusta, no obstante no desello cambiar los valores de las otras columnas con null ya que estos traen datos de activación. 
se podra hacer esto ?  A.Guiee_active = if( c=2, b, A.Guiee_active ) ...

Comment: Sí. Tal como lo pusiste.

Comment: Excelente, gracias por tu aporte. me ayudaste mucho